# visual c++ while loop isn't properly working

Tags: visual-studio, loops, visual-c++, while-loop

I was trying win32 api and wrote a c++ header to help me with the window creation and handling but when I tried to run this the thread kept running because the while condition kept evaluated to true. I tried putting break point for the loop and checked each time if the condition should be true but this time the loop exited, so now I am left confused on why that happend. I also tried disabling optimization but to no avail. i am using visual studio community 2019, please let me know if u can help me solve this issue cause i don't know what else to do.

```
// file : main.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include"app.hpp"
int main() {
    app app;

    try {
        app.init();
        while (!app.exit) {
            app.update();
        }
    } catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "caught exception : " << e.what() << std::endl;
    } catch (...) {
        std::cerr << "caught unknow exception!" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

// file : app.cpp

#include "app.hpp"

window startup(800, 500, L"startup window", Y_size_Y_window);
int app::init(){
    startup.show(SHOW);
    return 0;
}

void app::update() { 

// previous code

    // if (startup.msg.message == WM_QUIT)
    //     exit = true;
    // handle_msg(startup);

// new code
    
    while (PeekMessage(&startup.msg, nullptr, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) {
        if (startup.msg.message == WM_QUIT)
            exit = true;
        TranslateMessage(&startup.msg);
        DispatchMessageW(&startup.msg); }

}
```

edit : I changed the code a little bit, I tried to process all the messages waiting in queue at once, but the problem occurs when i use the hwnd parameter in the peek message function. everything works fine if i leave that parameter null, but when i use `startup.wnd` in the function then the loops runs forever cause the WM_QUIT message never gets processed and for the rest of the infinite loop the only message that gets processed is WM_PAINT.

does this mean i can't process message for individual windows?
should i just use nullptr and build around that?
and what is causing causing this behaviour?
these are my only questions for now.

Comment: What is updating `startup.msg.message`?

Comment: @trojanfoe `#define handle_msg(a) { if (PeekMessage(&a.msg, a.wnd, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) { TranslateMessage(&a.msg); DispatchMessageW(&a.msg); } } `

Comment: It's usually unwise to run a busy loop based on `PeekMessage` - you are pegging CPU at 100% doing nothing. Try replacing `PeekMessage` with `GetMessage`, see if the behavior changes.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik  changed the code a little bit, i gave a little update as well, I think i was using peek message wrong so i changed the behaviour it gives is still confusing.

Comment: Right. `PostQuitMessage` doesn't take `HWND` as a parameter; the `WM_QUIT` message is not addressed to any window in particular. In any case, `PeekMessage` with a filter is almost always wrong, you want to retrieve and process all messages.